# Error Saving and getting blob from database SQL oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to save a CLOB into the database and recovering it, but I'm getting an SQLException:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lob read/write functions called while another read/write is in progress: getBytes()
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getBytes(T4CConnection.java:2427)
 at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBytes(BLOB.java:348)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:181)
```

I figured that the problem is when I tried to get the CLOB, because it's still saving. 
If the CLOB is small it works fine, but when the CLOB is a little bigger it fails.

Sorry about my english and thanks

EDIT:

The annotation is:

```
@Lob
@Column(nullable = false)
private String body;
```

The save method

```
emailRepository.save(email);
```

Comment: And why does it have anything to do with Spring or Hibernate?

Comment: please post the code where this exception is thrown?

Comment: Also, please show us your entity with annotations/xml

Comment: The annotation is  
@Lob
@Column(nullable = false)
private String body;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the hibernate property

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
```

sorved the problem for me.

Setting the lobCreator for SessionFactory to NonContextualLobCreator is probably a better solution (not tried yet).

However I'm not sure what causes this error.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem in one of the projects, setting

> updatable = false

fixed the issue for me.

Example:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "CONTENT", updatable = false)
Blob content;
```

Hibernate somehow tries to re-save the content, even when it was not changed.