# Lob read/write while another in progress

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm playing with

- Hibernate 5.0.7
- Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE
- Spring Data Jpa 1.9.2.RELEASE
- Oracle XE 11.2.0.4
- Java 8 / Maven 3

Here is my data model:

[image]

Full source code of my application can be found on [my GitHub branch](https://github.com/pduleba/spring-data-jpa/tree/branch/JPARepository_Problem). It has 
`main()` defined in `Main` class and database is auto generated on start up on existing schema of running Oracle.

During execution I faced exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
    at com.pduleba.spring.data.services.OwnerServiceImpl.update(OwnerServiceImpl.java:34)
    at com.pduleba.spring.data.controller.DBControllerImpl.update(DBControllerImpl.java:60)
    at com.pduleba.spring.data.controller.DBControllerImpl.createDB(DBControllerImpl.java:36)
    at com.pduleba.Main.execute(Main.java:49)
    at com.pduleba.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3071)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2950)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3330)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:486)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:454)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IOException while reading stream. Transaction should be rolled back.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:555)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Lob read/write functions called while another read/write is in progress: getBytes()
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:204)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.readInternal(OracleBufferedStream.java:169)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.read(OracleBufferedStream.java:143)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConversionInputStream.needBytesFromStream(OracleConversionInputStream.java:334)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConversionInputStream.needBytes(OracleConversionInputStream.java:211)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConversionInputStream.needBytes(OracleConversionInputStream.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.readInternal(OracleBufferedStream.java:169)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.read(OracleBufferedStream.java:143)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.marshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:804)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshalBinds(T4C8Oall.java:1777)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshal(T4C8Oall.java:1114)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lob read/write functions called while another read/write is in progress: getBytes()
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getBytes(T4CConnection.java:2427)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBytes(BLOB.java:348)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:181)
    ... 67 more
```

To my understanding, my problem is related to persisting `spec` and `image` properties of `CarModel` entity. They are mapped as [java.sql.Blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) and [java.sql.Clob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html). Problem appears almost every execution. When I map `spec` as `String` and `image` as `byte[]` it works without problem.

I tried solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370468/error-saving-and-getting-blob-from-database-sql-oracle) but it do not work. As I checked in [Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html), there is no **hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults** property.

Could someone help me figure out what Am I doing wrong?

Thank You for all of the answers.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `String` and `byte[]`? Since `Blob` and `Clob` are part of the `java.sql` package they seem to be intended for direct JDBC operations.

Comment: Btw, if you search the net for `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` you'll find references to it - it just seems to not be mentioned in the official documentation.

Comment: ORM mappers remove the need for things like Blob and Clob and you should be using String etc as advised above.

Comment: Hi @NeilStockton and @Thomas - Thank You for Your reponse. I would like to check scenerio when in my DB there are big clob/blob. I'm verifying how to stream those data instead loading whole object into JVM memory as pointed [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#LOBs.2C_BLOBs.2C_CLOBs_and_Serialization) Mayby it is not possible as pointed : `these require a live connection, so may have issues with detached objects`

Comment: you refer to the docs for the EclipseLink JPA implementation? (written by its authors), so not necessarily applicable to other JPA implementations. Consult the docs of your implementation.

Comment: Ok thanks for that hint. I will do that.

Comment: Any result to this problem?